# How to remove CURL time limit in PHP?

Tags: php

I am running a rather long script that fetches the contents of a specified domain and parses the html before running a series of tests on said html. Anyway the script times out after a while. I tried putting this at the top of my page but still no luck:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Here is the error in question:

```
cURL error number:28
cURL error:Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 316183 out of 6476018 bytes received
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to set the amount of time curl gets to complete its operations with curl_setopt.

The CURLOPT_TIMEOUT setting to be specific.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); // the timeout in seconds
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 4):

Use the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` option in conjunction with `curl_setopt()`.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // zero waits indefinitely
```

`set_time_limit()` only sets how long the script can run.  The issue you're having is a cURL timout.

http://php.net/curl-setopt

Comment: CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.  VS  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT  The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

Comment: @profitphp: But as far as the manual is concerned, there is no such option as `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

[Set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) to a higher value.

Comment: Setting CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to a higher value won't remove the time limit.  Setting it to zero (0) will.  The same goes for CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS. ( source: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html / http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS.html )