# Curl get huge xml string

Tags: php, curl

I have **php** code to get xml string consist of city in world . but when i want show xml result xml string not complete receive

```
$ch = curl_init( 'http://city.com/getcities/' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
$response_xml = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
```

[image]

in many request i can get only 5000 to 6000 line and after string split and not show .

- Sorry for my poor english

Comment: You could try to extend `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` a value greater than 90 or 0. Maybe [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858104/how-to-remove-curl-time-limit-in-php) can be helpful.

Comment: thanks . not working . i get xml string very fast but i dont know why not complete

Comment: The URL you list appears to be down. Was there documentation for their API? If there was documentation why are you fetching so much at once? If you are pulling information for a webpage there are several timeouts you may be hitting. If you are performing a CLI based php call to fill a database you may still need to look at the API and break up your request into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found problem . because i used 4G mobile network . after switch to ADSL work perfect .